# How to change the background color of ToolStripItems?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip, toolstripitem, toolstripcombobox

When I add a `ToolStripMenuItem` to a `ContextMenuStrip` and then add a `ToolStripComboBox` in it, the background color under the `ToolStripComboBox` isn't blue. However, as you can see it's blue under 'Sub opt2' (which is in the main options of `ContextMenuStrip`).

**My question:** How can you change the background that's underneath the `ToolStripComboBox`?

The Image below is an example of the these two `ToolStripComboBox` having different background colors:

[image]

The Image below is an example of the background color I want to change:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your `Sub opt1` ToolStripMenuItem is named **`options1ToolStripMenuItem`**:

you can remove the margin reserved to the Image, casting its `DropDown` (which is of type [`ToolStripDropDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown)) to [`ToolStripDropDownMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdownmenu):

```
(options1ToolStripMenuItem.DropDown as ToolStripDropDownMenu).ShowImageMargin = false;
```

Using the same logic, you can also set the BackColor of the DropDown (not the BackColor of single `ToolStripItems`. If you change the BackColor of a [ToolStripComboBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripcombobox), as in this case, you just change the property value of the Control itself):

```
options1ToolStripMenuItem.DropDown.BackColor = [Your Color];
```

You can add this code to the Form's Constructor.
You need to repeat the same operation to *configure* other sub-menus.